# Create a WSDL in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, eclipse-kepler

I want to create a new WSDL in Eclipse Kepler.

In project, New-->Other-->Webservices and New-->Other-->XML, I could not find them.

Do I need to install any new plugin?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftcrtwsdl.html

Comment: Under Webservices, the option WSDL is not listed for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found it. In the new-file wizard, the "WSDL file" entry is not under "XML" but under "Web Services". And yes, you have to install some package to get it. I don't know which one exactly, it must have been either *Eclipse Web developer tools*, *Eclipse XML Editor and tools* or *Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools*, probably the latter.